# concat value of a resolved promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angularjs-components

Task: 
I have a function `playlist.expand()` that returns a promise with data like `[Item1, Item2, Item3]`. I have a collection of these playlists and want to concat the data returned from all `expand()` functions and return it as a flat array. However I am stuck in the following code. I am hoping a few extra pair of eyes could help me spot the error:

Code:

```
breakdownPlaylist() {
    return this.playlists.reduce( (acc, playlist) => {
        acc.push( playlist.expand().then(result => result.collection));
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

$onInit() {
    console.log('test', this.breakdownPlaylist());
}
```

Issue:
test is equal to `[]` at the time of execution. I can't understand why.

Comment: I think there is one missing bracket at line 3 in above code. Can you check that?

Comment: Issues around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call are only part of the problem here, therefore I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree. My issue is not returning the value of a promise but combining values returned from multiple promises.

Comment: hey @HarshPatel, I have checked for missing brackets. There are no syntax errors. The ending concat parenthesis is after `result.collection`

Comment: Remember that `Array#concat()`, unlike `Array#push()` returns a new array leaving the original array unmodified. That should explains why test is equal to `[]`, though it's not the whole answer.

Comment: One more reopen vote, and I'll give you a proper solution.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks for the comment about `Array.push()`. I noticed that last night and now using push instead of concat.